# Truffle Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined after using migrate

Tags: truffle

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x-6ruqmNS3o&t=910s).
After using the command `truffle migrate --reset` the blocks appear on Ganache GUI. However, I'm not able to interact with the contract using the console. If I type `token = await MemoryToken.deployed()`, I receive the following error:

```
truffle(development)> let token = await MemoryToken.deployed()
Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined at evalmachine.<anonymous>:2:19
```

I have no idea why. I tried this several time with the same result. What am I missing ?

The same happens with [the tutorial from the truffle website](https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/quickstart#creating-a-project).

Comment: Great question. Just started experiencing this as well. I can test it via truffle test, but can't interact with it via truffle console (after I manually migrate). Same error.

Comment: downgrade the truffle version to 5.4.3

Comment: @ovo It works thank you very much. Do you have any idea why this happen with truffle v5.4.5 ?

Answer (score 9):

A temporary workaround is to explicitly define `global` in the REPL:

```
global = this
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
truffle(development)> let token = MemoryToken.deployed()
```

It worked for me. I don't know much more about the error

Comment: Can somebody outline the logic that makes this solution work?

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue. Changed node version from v12.22.4 to v10.16.0.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the MetaCoin example with Truffle v5.4.5 (core: 5.4.5), Solidity v0.5.16 (solc-js), Node v14.14.0, Web3.js v1.5.1. It works after downgrading Truffle to version v5.4.3 as suggested by @ovo.